# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Robotics Stack Exchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [covariance matrix in EKF?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2365/covariance-matrix-in-ekf)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Benefits of the Number of Propellers](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/benefits-of-the-number-of-propellers)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [problem with simulated sensor in Matlab?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/problem-with-simulated-sensor-in-matlab)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Cons and pros of wireless technologies for rescue robot](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2357/cons-and-pros-of-wireless-technologies-for-rescue-robot)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Quadrocopter first build: how to tell if components play well together?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2453/quadrocopter-first-build-how-to-tell-if-components-play-well-together)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Generic name for two-motor wheeled/tracked robots?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2396/generic-name-for-two-motor-wheeled-tracked-robots)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Quadcopter Props? Wood vs Plastic vs Carbon Fiber](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/quadcopter-props-wood-vs-plastic-vs-carbon-fiber)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Android phone + ADK + Arducopter APM 2.5 for autonomous quadcopter](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/android-phone-adk-arducopter-apm-2-5-for-autonomous-quadcopter)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Just run program on NXT, not download?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/just-run-program-on-nxt-not-download)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is minimum torque required for CNC stepper motors and spindle for aluminium milling?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/what-is-minimum-torque-required-for-cnc-stepper-motors-and-spindle-for-aluminium)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see with robotics.SE is the huge income of overly broad questions. Open the first page and you'd see many many questions that ask for "I have some general idea, would it be at all possible?" or "what project do your recommend if I'm interested in X?" or "I want to start a project for doing X, do you have some references?" and the like.

I don't know what can be done with them to be effective, but something seems to me that needs to be done. Simply closing them is probably not well enough since the questions are still visible and occupying the first page, giving the impression to newcomers that the website is indeed for those kind of questions.